# Filtering out substring from NSString . . .maybe using regex

Tags: objective-c, ios, regex, nsstring

Here is my problem:

I am trying to filter out html tags from an NSString object.

Most fixes for this simply remove everything falling between a < and a >, as well as those characters themselves. I am trying to figure out a way to remove the "< . . . >" substring ONLY if it does not contain white space or newline characters.

The way i was thikning about doing it looks something like this

```
while ([source rangeOfString@"someRegEx" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch].location != NSNotFound) {

//find the range of the substring
//check for newlines/whitespace characters
//replace occurrences of the string with "" if it doesn't have them

}
```

Firstly, does this seem like a good approach? Secondly, I'm having a lot of problems with figuring out what that regex would look like... does anyone have any ideas what it might look like?

Comment: Do you really want to keep all tags that have spaces inside them? What about `<a href="...">`? Or do you mean, if there are **not only** whitespace characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a fine approach, provided the tags you're looking for **really never contain whitespace**, as m.buettner points out. The regex would look something like this:

`<[^\s]*?>`

The `[^\s]` is a negated character class which matches anything but whitespace characters. The `?` makes the `*` lazy instead of greedy. So this regex in English means "Match a '<', then the smallest possible number of non-whitespace characters, then a '>'."

[This is a helpful page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html).

Comment: to grab any expression with a "<anything>" would you just do something like "<*>" ?

Comment: <.*> will match < then 0 or more characters then >. <*> will actually just match 0 or more <s then >.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider employing an `NSXMLParser`, described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

You get quite a rich set of [delegate methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to extract whatever you like from the string.